# Running a Python script inside of an R script

Tags: python, r

I would like to run a python script inside of my R script. To this end, I use the below instruction:

```
system(cat("py -2.7 -i C:/Users/Dropbox/Mong/PythonCode.py",
"s = shelve.open('C:/Users/Dropbox/Mong/AG1')",
"model = s['AG1']",
"M = model.Matrix",
"m = len(M)",
"string  = ''",
"string += ';'.join([','.join([str(x) for x in M[i]]) for i in range(m)])",
"string += ';'",
"f = open('C:/Users/Dropbox/Mong/AG1.txt','w')",
"f.write(string)",
"f.close()",
"quit()", sep='\n'))
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error in system(command, as.integer(flag), f, stdout, stderr) : 
  character string expected as first argument
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, give `system` a character string. `cat` returns an invisible `NULL` (and there is rarely a reason to use it in R). You probably want to use `paste` instead,

Comment: Well, that's not an R error anymore. Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, it is from R. I can run this code by directly pasting it in R shell.

Comment: I understand that. But the error is not returned by R but by python.